# Setup a VPN(L2TP) connection on circleCI

Tags: linux, continuous-integration, yaml, vpn, circleci

I have to set up a pipeline for some cypress tests on a website that is protected by a WAF.

I use circleCi for this. I can't find any working examples. I did try to flow this [tutorial.](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/docs/clients.md#configure-linux-vpn-clients-using-the-command-line) but because I'm a newbie with circleCI I can't replicate that in a pipeline.

Does anybody have a working pipeline that connects to a VPN? or any good documentation about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this Orb: https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/kindred/kin-l2tp-vpn.

Seems like a good solution.